# Train doc2vec for company name similarity

Tags: word2vec, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

I am trying to deduplicate a huge list of companies (40M+) using the name similarities.  I have a 500K of company name pairs labelled same/not-same (like I.B.M.=International Business Machines). Model built by logistic regression on vector difference of name pairs has a great f-score (0.98) but the inference (finding the most similar names) is too slow (almost 2 secs per name).

Is it possible to train doc2vec model using name similarity pairs (positive and negative), resulting in similar names has similar vectors so that I can use fast vector similarities algorithms like Annoy?

Answer (score 3):

Searching for the top-N nearest-neighbors in high-dimensional spaces is hard. To get a perfectly accurate top-N typically requires an exhaustive search, which is probably the reason for your disappointing performance.

When some indexing can be applied, as with the ANNOY library, some extra indexing time and index-storage is required, and accuracy is sacrificed because some of the true top-N neighbors can be missed.

You haven't mentioned how your existing vectors are created. You don't need to adopt a new vector-creation method (like doc2vec) to use indexing; you can apply indexing libraries to your existing vectors.

If your existing vectors are sparse (as for example if they are big bag-of-character-n-grams representations, with many dimensions but most 0.0), you might want to look into Facebook's [PySparNN](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn) library.

If they're dense, in addition to the ANNOY you mentioned, Facebook [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) can be considered.

But also, even the exhaustive search-for-neighbors is highly parallelizable: split the data into M shards on M different systems, and finding the top-N on each is often close to 1/Nth the time of the same operation on the full index, then merging the M top-N lists relatively quick. So if finding the most-similar is your key bottleneck, and you need the top-N most-similar in say 100ms, throw 20 machines at 20 shards of the problem.

(Similarly, the top-N results for all may be worth batch-calculating. If you're using cloud resources, rent 500 machines to do 40 million 2-second operations, and you'll be done in under two days.)

Comment: Gojomo, thanks for the effort. Yes, I do have a huge n-grams representation that is sparse (40434120,487654). The slowest part is subtracting query vector from corpus matrix (csr_matrix) to prepare for the logistic regression. That is why I am looking for some vector representation that will enable some ANN searching to get top n results (on which then I can do exact search)